# CakePHP add action in Jquery modal window

Tags: jquery, cakephp, modal-dialog, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I have written add action for categories controller. Where in I have included jquery modal window for add form of categories.

The code for modal as below.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="AddModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
        &#215;
    </button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Add Category</h3>
</div> 
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo $this -> Form -> create('Stock'); ?>
        <fieldset>
                <div class="control-group">
                     <?php echo $this -> Form -> label('Name'); ?>
                     <div class="controls">
                         <?php echo $this -> Form -> text('InventoryCategory.name', array('class' => 'input-xlarge', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Category name here...', 'required' => false)); ?>
                         <?php echo $this -> Form -> error('InventoryCategory.name', array('class' => 'error-message')); ?>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="control-group">
                     <?php echo $this -> Form -> label('Parent Category'); ?>
                     <div class="controls">
                         <?php echo $this -> Form -> select('InventoryCategory.inventory_category_id', null, array('value' => '', 'class' => 'input-xlarge')); ?>
                         <?php echo $this -> Form -> error('InventoryCategory.inventory_category_id', array('class' => 'error-message')); ?>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="control-group">
                     <?php echo $this -> Form -> label('Description'); ?>
                     <div class="controls">
                         <?php echo $this -> Form -> textarea('InventoryCategory.description', array('class' => 'input-xlarge', 'rows' => '3', 'placeholder' => 'Some description or notes goes in here....')); ?>
                         <?php echo $this -> Form -> error('InventoryCategory.description', array('class' => 'error-message')); ?>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <?php echo $this -> Form -> button('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this -> Form -> end(); ?>
</div>
```

I have included ajax call for saving data.
The code for javascript as below.

```
    $('#AddModal').on('shown', function() {
        $.getJSON('<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'stocks', 'action'=>'categories', true)); ?>', function(data) {
            var options = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
                options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });
            $("#InventoryCategoryInventoryCategoryId").html(options);
        })
    });

    $('#StockCategoriesForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var name    = $("#InventoryCategoryName").val();
        var categoryId  = $("#InventoryCategoryInventoryCategoryId").val();
        var description   = $("#InventoryCategoryDescription").val(); 

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'stocks', 'action'=>'add_category'))?>",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: '{"InventoryCategory":{"name":"'+name+'", "categoryId": "'+categoryId+'", "description": "'+description+'"}}', // here build JSON object with your form data
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            complete: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                if(result.response == true) {
                    $("#InventoryCategoryName").val(null);
                    $("#InventoryCategoryInventoryCategoryId").val(null);
                    $("#InventoryCategoryDescription").val(null);
                    location.reload();
                    $('#AddModal').modal('hide');
                    alert('inserted');
                } else {
                    alert('not inserted');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The categories are saving but the modal is not getting close itself and I wanted `Cakephp Model` validation errors in that `Jquery Modal` only. Is this what I am writing is correct or if it is wrong please suggest me some solutions. The work is more appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location.reload() is most probably at fault. The cleanest way to do this is to get rendered HTML instead of JSON from the POST call and replace the dialog contents with it. This way you leave form building to CakePHP.

On success, you can for example return a window with a "close" button, or you embed a  tag which closes the modal.

```
var $form = $('#StockCategoriesForm');
$form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'stocks', 'action'=>'add_category'))?>",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: $form.serialize(),
        complete: function(result) {
            $('#AddModal').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```